# install ubuntu alongside windows11,can't boot windows now ,grub doesn't work

Tags: dual-boot

1. secure boot disable
2. installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
3. two OSes intalled on the same ssd
4. I tried update grub (sudo update-grub)[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvu8A.jpg)
5. reboot pc its stop at[black interface blinking cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDmC6.jpg)
   and then open ubuntu[desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDuty.jpg)

Comment: So ... you see the blinking cursor ... then you open Ubuntu? Apologies, but point-form *really* doesn't work for your type of question. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you installed (1) full sentences (2) whether Ubuntu boots eventually or not at all (3) how you are trying to update the Grub boot loader. With this, it may be possible for someone to offer some assistance 

Comment: Also what brand/model system? Grub only boots working Windows, so fast start up must  be off which uses hibernation flag and no hibernation and chkdsk not needed. Can you boot Windows directly from UEFI boot menu?

Comment: @oldfred.Thx for that info.I am using msi motherboard.It doesn't have fast start option in BIOS.I can't boot windows directly from boot menu

Comment: some bios have an option that disallow the OS to write on the UEFI partition. grub will be properly installed unless you set this option properly.

Comment: @PedroRolo How should I set it

Comment: you should set it in a way that the OS is allowed to write to the UEFI partition.This option is likely to be in the security section of the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Some computers have a bios option that prevents the OS write to the UEFI partition. You should first try to disable this option. Other thing you can do is to set the bios to boot in CSM mode instead of UEFI mode. When trying this last option you might have to run grub-update again, or even grub-install specifying which harddrive should have it's MBR modified. e.g.

> grub-install /dev/sda

Needless to say that when using CSM mode and grub-install you will have to set the hard drive that you will have run grub-install against as your boot device on the boot options.